# rmmod buggy network driver

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, modprobe

I suspect I have a buggy network driver for an Atheros `ath9k` device as I will eventually get SW IOMMU errors.  Sometimes when this happens, I can simply `rmmod` and `modprobe` it back and it will start working.  Other times, I must actually remove the device by disconnecting it.  And, if I wait too long, I suppose, it causes too much trouble to the point where I cannot `rmmod` or unplug the device.  If I do so, the system will hang indefinitely.

Since I don't plan on fixing the driver (I'm not a firmware developer), is it a good "enough" fix to simply `rmmod` and `modprobe` the driver periodically or will that also not work?

Comment: Disable the power management

Comment: hmm, good point, I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: unfortunately, it is already disabled.  I checked the wiki and it is disabled by default.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

I am a kernel developer, so I can tell you that "it depends". It's not impossible that a proactive remove and re-insert of a driver could keep a bug away, like an apple a day versus doctor. It depends on the bug.

A great example of a problem for which rmmod can be a workaround is a runaway memory allocation in the driver (a *de facto* leak) such that the driver hasn't lost track of the memory and is able to clean it up at rmmod time.

If the bug is instability caused by corruption, then it's unlikely to be a workaround, though possible.  Suppose that the problem plays out in several steps: first the driver has to get into some relatively rare state S (perhaps an invalid state) and then some relatively rare event E has to occur while it is in that state. (If E occurs and the driver is not in state S, then the issue doesn't reproduce.)  If rmmod and re-insertion get the driver out of state S, and is done periodically then the problem becomes less reproducible.

Removal and re-insertion can have problems of their own, such as introducing leaks (the driver doesn't clean up everything on rmmod) or leaving behind dangling pointers (the driver deallocates some object, but doesn't properly deregister it from all its associations). When developing dynamic drivers, one test case should be a shell script that does a rmmod/insmod in a loop. (That doesn't provide full coverage of course: you also need `insmod; various actual use cases of driver; rmmod` in a loop).

Comment: You raise a good point, that would probably be a relatively simple test to do.  Write a loop, say, test it 1000, 10000, 100000 times and see what that does to memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest version of `ath9k` from backports to solve some problems as : " Wifi keep disconnecting " , "Internet is slowly " , " cannot `rmmod/modprobe` ...

Download and install the latest backports:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
make defconfig-ath9k
make -j 16
make install
```

When everythig is done successfully , you will get :

```
Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.
```

Run the following command to load the driver at boot then reboot:

```
echo "ath9k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
reboot
```

Reload the driver:

```
rmmod ath9k
modprobe ath9k
```

Comment: I am on the 4.7.4 kernel ... so I don't think that would apply.

Comment: @WalterWhite please add the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `iwconfig`